# Time needed to heat water in a pot

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> I have a pot with water of mass $m$ and it is heated by a stove
>   element of temperature $T_E$ and with a surface area of $A$.  The
>   water starts at temperature $T_W > 0^\circ\, C$.
>
> How long would it take to heat up this water to a final temperature of
>   $T_F$ ($T_W<T_F < 100^\circ \, C$)?  Metal of the pot is negligible.

The heat travels with convection in the water, presumably.  I was trying to figure out a solution to this problem, but I am unsure as to what formula to use.

Would the answer change if someone is constantly stirring?

Comment: Hi Argon, this isn't a homework help site.  You'll need to adjust your question to cover some conceptual problem you're having with the problem.

Comment: @BrandonEnright This is not homework; I made the question for myself.  If you would like to see what I have done, I tried to use Newton's law of cooling to get $T(t) = T_E + (T_W - T_E) e^{-\frac{hA}{mc}t}$.

Comment: Do you have a pot? Do you have water? This is the kind of thing you can answer with a stove and a stopwatch better than with pencil and paper.

Comment: Okay.  Instead putting this topic on hold because I am not asking "about a specific physics concept," treat this as a homework question and point me in the right direction.  I am able to do the neccisary math and computation, but I am unable to find a formula that involves all the parameters I would like.  Instead of closing this question, could someone please give me some kind of *hint*?  Or if not, could someone tell me how to phrase a question properly so I can get such a formula?

Comment: It depends on how you're heating it. For a stove situation, Newton's law of cooling (but adapted to heating) is probably nonphysical. When a pot boils, the heat is being transferred to it through contact of the coils with the bottom of the pot. If the pot bottom is sufficiently thin metal, than since the coil temperature (in Kelvin) is far higher than either the hot or the cold water temperature, it is a reasonable approximation to assume that the heat transfer rate from the coils to the water through the metal pot bottom due to Fourier's law is constant.

Comment: Thus the water temperature will increase linearly over time, neglecting radiative and evaporative cooling. At the boiling point, evaporative cooling will suddenly dominate, and the water temperature will stabilize ate 373K. Thus the water temperature will roughly be a piecewise function of time, being approximately linearly increasing during the heating portion, and roughly flat when boiling is reached. Does this help? Finding the rate of quasi-linear increase during the heating portion then becomes a question of how good the contact between the coils and the pot is.